# Mixed Model with repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, mixed-model

first off all, excuse  my English; it's not my primary language.

I'm watching water table recharge and salinity because of Land Use Change in semiarid system. I´m particularly concerned with the interaction between forest and different types of agriculture (in other words, I'm trying to see if forest absorb the excess water that we found in agriculture) so:

- I have at least 17 transects of 6 holes each.
- Each transect is a replicate of my design. (It's a random effect. Let's call it `transect`.)
- Each transect goes from the middle of the forest patch to the middle of an agriculture patch. So the distance from the hole to the center of the forest patch is a fixed effect in which I'm very interested.  Let's call it `distance`.
- Each hole has 8 depth measures (depth is a fixed effect repeated in depth - repeated measure). Let's call them `depth`
- I have three places where I made measurements:  this is a fixed effect in which I´m not interested (3 levels). Let´s call it `Place`.
- The response variables are `water content` and `chloride`

I´m reading *Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R* by Zuur et al. But I find a little bit difficult and I need a short cut to find out what to write in R ...